# Is there a way to explicitely ignore agruments declared in function signature

Tags: php, arguments, custom-function

Sometimes, especially with callbacks functions or inheritance/implementation case, I don't want to use some arguments in method. But they are required by the method interface signature (and I can't change the signature, let's say it's something required via Composer). Example:

```
// Assuming the class implements an interface with this method:
// public function doSomething($usefull1, $usefull2, $usefull3);

public function doSomething($usefull, $useless_here, $useless_here) {
    return something_with($usefull);
}
// ...
```

In some other languages (let's say Rust), I can ignore these arguments explicitly, which make the code (and intention) more readable. In PHP, it could be this:

```
public function doSomething($usefull, $_, $_) {
    return something_with($usefull);
}
```

Is this possible in PHP? Did I missed something?

*Side note: it's not only for trailing arguments, it could be anywhere in the function declaration*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can hope for is to give them unique names that will suggest that they will not be used in the call.

Perhaps:

```
function doSomething($usefull,$x1,$x2){
    return something_with($usefull);
}
```

Or:

```
function doSomething($ignore1,$useful,$ignore2){
    return something_with($useful);
}
```

PHP wants to have arguments accounted for and uniquely named.

---

Edit:  If you want to avoid declaring variables that you won't use (but you know they are being sent), try [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) and [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php). This should make the code lean, clean, readable.  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eea5574081767d1d29c1c0985caec30078329668))

```
function test(){
    // get only use argument 2
    list(,$useful,)=func_get_args();
    echo $useful;
}

test('one','two','three');  // outputs: two
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just wait for some other answer before accepting yours, in case somebody else know a different approach.

Comment: @rap-2-h that's okay, I recommend that you never rush the green tick as a matter of good practice on StackOverflow.

Comment: @rap-2-h it just occurred to me that `func_get_args()` with `list()` will effectively "clean up" your function.  Have a look at my update.

Answer (score 1):

Assign default value for optional parameter.

```
function doSomething($usefull,$useless1=null,$useless2=null){
    return something_with($usefull); 
    }
```

Now.... 
Parameter 1 is required
Parameter 2 is optional
Parameter 3 is optional

Call function like..

```
doSomething($data);
doSomething($data,$anotherData);
doSomething($data,$anotherData,$anotherData1);
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't deal with what the OP is asking.  And the useless arguments can be in any position.

Comment: Also make first argument optional (usefull equal to null) and then check all arguments in function and do something whatever you want.

Comment: This is not a solution (despite receiving an upvote from someone).  Setting default values to these arguments does nothing to nullify the values.  The `null` value would only be assigned in the absence of the argument when the function is called.  The OP is saying the he is not in control of the function call; only the function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Your concrete object does not fit the interface completly, so you can just add a adapter class between them. So the interface stay as it is and your object just get what it really need.

```
class Adapter extends CustomInterface
{
    function doSomething($ignore1,$useful,$ignore2){
        return $customClass->something_with($useful);
    }
}
```